How to display data in laravel nova from file instead of model?
This is a data in countries.php file
i need to display it into country nova resource but i don't want to use country model
return [
    'all' => [
        [
            'alpha2code' => 'AF',
            'alpha3code' => 'AFG',
            'calling_code' => '93',
            'capital' => 'Kabul',
            'region' => 'Asia',
            'sub_region' => 'Southern Asia',
            'latitude' => '33',
            'longitude' => '65',
            'timezone' => 'UTC+04:30',
            'numeric_code' => '004',

            'name' => [
                'en' => 'Afghanistan',
                'ar' => 'أفغانستان',
            ],
        ],
        [
            'alpha2code' => 'AX',
            'alpha3code' => 'ALA',
            'calling_code' => '358',
            'capital' => 'Mariehamn',
            'region' => 'Europe',
            'sub_region' => 'Northern Europe',
            'latitude' => '60.116667',
            'longitude' => '19.9',
            'timezone' => 'UTC+02:00',
            'numeric_code' => '248',

            'name' => [
                'en' => 'Åland Islands',
                'ar' => 'جزر آلاند',
            ],
        ],
];

i'm trying to use indexQuery() in country nova resource
public static function indexQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query): Builder|Collection
{
    $countries = config('countries.all');
    return collect($countries);
}

but nothing returns
